# Laravel api project swagger returns error

Tags: php, laravel, swagger

I have just implemented a little api using Laravel. 
Now I'm traying to document it using swagger.
I just added the following dependency "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "^5.5" in composer.json
When I'm trying to genereate it using the following command: php artisan l5-swagger:generate

I receive the next error message:
[Error Required @OA\Info() not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdkbC.png)

[Location Myproject/vendor/zircote/swagger-php/src/Logger.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvF2g.png)
I don't understand why the error is casued if Logger.php is auto created after "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "^5.5".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a @OA\Info to describe the project see bellow:

```
/**
* @OA\Info(title="API", version="0.0.1")
**/
```

Comment: I tried in different ways but it stills appearing the same issue. In the way you said @loic.lopez

Comment: protected function __construct()
    {
        /**
         * param \Exception|string $entry
         * param int $type Error type
         */
        $this->log = function ($entry, $type) {
            if ($entry instanceof Exception) {
                $entry = $entry->getMessage();
            }
            /**
            * @OA\Info(title="API", version="0.0.1")
            **/
            trigger_error($entry, $type);
        };
    }  Returns the same error

Comment: @notarealgreal see https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger/issues/152

Comment: and the sample code https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger/blob/634469942ad015199aea33eb5f2ce25b97abec1b/tests/storage/annotations/OpenApi/Anotations.php

Comment: @loic.lopez , I installed darkaonline/l5-swagger and in api/documentation url had this error : " Error Required @OA\Info() not found" , my laravel version is 5.6 , so in base controller I added:  * @OA\Info(title="Automation", version="0.0.1") so It worked